# Getting HttpStatus from WCF Rest Client

Tags: rest, wcf-client, http-status-codes, wcf-rest

As i've mentioned in topic. I have WCF Rest Service, and ASP.NET MVC3 client. In ASP's controller i'm using

```
IMyService serviceClient = new WebChannelFactory<IMyService>().CreateChannel();
```

to create client (channel) for my service. Is there any way to attach to this channel and get HttpStatusCode for each response from WebService? Btw should I close channel after each request-response? or it could be opened for next EndUser requests via ASP.NET MVC3 app?

I'm setting HttpStatusCode in webService through

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = <HttpStatusCode>;
```

And i'd like to check it in MVC3 app and show proper hint.

**EDIT:**
Nevermind. I've found answers.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163302.aspx

Comment: You should do answers as _answers_ so they can be marked as such.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[AnswerLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163302.aspx)

Comment: this doesn't exist any more?